# How to make such a $N(0,1)$ sketch for standard normal Z?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

[image]

My attempt:

```
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], {x, -4, 4} , AxesLabel -> {None, "Z"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[{PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], 
    ConditionalExpression[PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], x >= #]}, 
   {x, -4, 4}, Filling -> {2 -> Axis}, FillingStyle -> Orange, 
   Ticks -> {{{#, Row[{"Z = " , ToString@#}]}}, Automatic}, 
   AxesLabel -> {None, "Z"}] &@2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Add the option

```
Epilog -> {Style[Text["p = " <> 
     ToString[N@SurvivalFunction[NormalDistribution[], #]], {1 + #, 
     PDF[NormalDistribution[], # - .5]}], 16],
  Arrow[{{1 + #, PDF[NormalDistribution[], # - .4]}, {# + .25, 
     PDF[NormalDistribution[], # + .75]}}]}
```

to get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is that possible to include the arrows and the labellings of p as well?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
Show[{Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], {x, -4, 4}, 
   AxesLabel -> {None, "Z"}],
  Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], {x, 2, 4}, 
   AxesLabel -> {None, "Z"}, Filling -> Bottom]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The easiest for the label is to add them with the drawing tools

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is that possible to include the arrows and the labellings of p as well?  Thanks!

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Invistigate the "Epilog" option if you want to add things like arrows and labels.